# Laravel: Automatically redirect users if route is not accessible with GET method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I work on a Laravel project with many routes and some of them are POST routes only so when a user type that route manually it shows them:
`The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

I found a solve for the problem by creating other routes with the same name but with GET and made them redirect to other pages.

**But I need to know if there is any other way (an automated way) instead of just creating a GET route for each post route**

Comment: If you just don't want to type the routes twice you can use `Route::match(['get', 'post'], ...)`

Comment: Why are you hitting a POST route using GET. If you are doing this on purpose to check your website does not break you can create a custom error page and display that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [fallback route](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#fallback-routes).
It should work in Laravel 5.6 and above. Make sure this is the last route in the list.

```
Route::fallback(function () {
//
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to register route that responds to multiple HTTP verbs. You may use `match` Or, you may even register a route that responds to all HTTP verbs using the `any` method.

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});

Route::any('/', function () {
    //
});
```